# Alterar Logo do sistema

Tags: angularjs, imagem, funções

Estou criando em um sistema que estou desenvolvendo para nosso cliente, uma função onde permite o mesmo fazer o upload da logo e cortar a mesma, em seguida quando ele salva estou tentando carregar a imagem que foi realizado o upload, mas acontece que preciso que sempre seja o mesmo nome e no mesmo destino e o navegador não consegue atualizar a mesma, por exemplo:

Nome atual da imagem = logo.png;

depois do upload o nome da imagem continua logo.png mas com outra imagem salva, pois se recarrego a página a logo é aplicada como deve, gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de fazer isso sem recarregar a pagina, segue o código que uso para setar a imagem:

```
$scope.carregarLogo = function(name){
    if($scope.img_name=== '' && angular.isUndefined(name) || name === ''){
       $scope.img_name = url_sistema + 'web_files/img/logo.png';
       $('#img').attr('src',$scope.img_name);
       console.log('deu');
    }else{
       $scope.img_name = name;
       $('#img').attr('src',$scope.img_name);
       console.log($('#img').attr('src'));
       console.log('deu2');
    }
};
```

Comment: +1. Já tive o mesmo problema mas não achei a solução, então contornei o problema usando `$window.location.reload();`

Comment: Techies, isso não resolve o problema. Só cria uma gambeta e impede você de entender o AngularJS da forma certa.

Comment: @JuanBiscaia Por isso dei o +1 e como comentei eu não achei a solução, e também disse que "contornei" o problema. Não disse que era a solução pro problema rs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Galera, achei uma solução aqui, dessa forma não preciso dar o reload na pagina, masss tem um único problema, não pode ser adicionado uma imagem com o nome que sempre será o mesmo (ex:logo.png) a pasta de onde será selecionada essa imagem para setar em algum , pois senão não vai funcionar, a unica forma de funcionar é quando eu crio o arquivo por PHP, porque ai não vai precisar substituir o arquivo que existe ai funciona, segue o código se quiserem testar, fiquem a vontade:

```
$scope.carregarLogo = function (name) {
    if ($scope.img_name === '' && angular.isUndefined(name) || name === '') {
        $scope.img_name = url_sistema + 'web_files/img/logo.png';
        $('#img').attr('src', $scope.img_name);
        console.log('deu');
    } else {
        var random = (new Date()).toString();
        $scope.img_name = name + "?date=" + random;
        console.log($scope.img_name);
        $('#img').attr('src', $scope.img_name);
        console.log($('#img').attr('src'));
        console.log('deu2');
    }
};
```

**AGRADEÇO A AJUDA DE VOCÊS, MUITO, UM ÓTIMO DIA A TODOS FLW**

Comment: A única doisa que acrecentei foi depois do }else{ var random = (new Date()).toString(); ------ e quando a a variável $scope.img_name recebe os dados, foi a única coisa que alterei, obrigado, espero que ajude vocês também

Comment: Que bom que você conseguiu resolver, mas uma coisa é certa, vc vai encontrar mais problemas pela frente, se continuar seguindo essa idéia de misturar Angular com jQuery, agora vc resolveu, mas logo vc vai começar a encontrar bugs mais "cabulosos" sem conseguir entender de onde eles estão saindo. Sua solução é valida para o seu problema, mas não serve como exemplo para mostrar como usar o AngularJS corretamente.

Comment: Entendi Juan, sei que misturar as linguagens não é recomendado, e também não é com toda certeza a melhor forma de resolver, agradeço pela sua ajuda amigo, tenha uma ótima tarde, até mais!

Answer (score 2):

Misturar AngularJS com jQuery dentro do seu controlador nunca é uma boa idéia, porque os dois são frameworks com propósitos diferentes. o jQuery é para manipulação do DOM e o AngularJS é para manipulação de dados com influencia sobre o DOM.

Basicamente, para resolver seu problema, você precisa **"pensar na maneira AngularJS"** e esquecer o que você conhece de jQuery, pelo menos no começo.

Uma possivel solução para seu problema:

```js
$scope.carregarLogo = function(name){
    if($scope.img_name=== '' && angular.isUndefined(name) || name === ''){
       $scope.img_name = url_sistema + 'web_files/img/logo.png';
    }else{
       $scope.img_name = name;
    }
};
```

```html
<div ng-controller="SeuController">
  <img ng-src="{{img_name}}">
</div>
```

Assumindo que sua function `carregarLogo` esta dentro de um controller. Note que no html estou usando uma directive nativa do angular, o [ngSrc](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc).

Agora voltando ao assunto "usar jQuery dentro do angular". Sempre que precisar fazer isso, crie uma directive para colocar suas manipulações de DOM dentro. E sempre que for mudar valores do $scope através de funções do jQuery use o `$scope.apply()` logo em seguida para atualizar os valores do escopo (dentro da directive).

Comment: Complementar ao que ele disse, "pensar na maneira AngularJS", você não precisa definir as funções sempre deste modo: `$scope.carregarLogo = function()`. Utilize essa definição somente se a função precisar ser chamada direto de sua view (de um arquivo html). Se ela estiver somente dentro do seu controller, não tem problema definir assim: `function carregarLogo()` ou `var carregarLogo = function()`. Pois ao definir um `$scope`, você cria um novo objeto ao $watcher, o que pode pesar sua aplicação a longo prazo.

Comment: Sim, e recomendo também ler padrões de design para criar aplicações mais claras, esse daqui é um que uso em muitos projetos e é ótimo tanto para grandes como para pequenos projetos. [AngularJS style guide em Portugues](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/i18n/pt-BR.md)